# Differences between ImageMagick and GraphicsMagick's defaults for the convert utility

Tags: imagemagick

I'm using `convert` to apply an HCLUT on an image. ImageMagick and GraphicsMagick both work, and both outputs have the same resolution, pixel density, metadata, etc.

Howerver GM's output is a lot smaller in filesize (~4mb vs 9mb for IM).
So my question is: 
Does GM apply any kind of lossy compression by default on conversion and IM doesn't ?

I'm not sure where the difference in filesize comes from.

Comment: What format are you saving as?

Comment: I'm not specifying an output format, I just run convert on a JPEG

Comment: Please share as much info as possible - especially the command line.